# Python Pandas: Call column name from column assignment

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
number_1 number_2 number_3 ... number_100 index
1        2        2000         8          3
201      10       21           2          1
...
```

I want to create a new column, which is equal to the `number_index` like this:

```
number_1 number_2 number_3 ... number_100 index number_index
1        2        2000         8          3     2000
201      10       21           2          1     201
...
```

Is something like `table['number_index'] = table['number_' + str(table['index'])]` possible?

Comment: Sorry bu I don't understand your example

Comment: First line: index = 3, I need `number_3` in `number_index`. Second line: index = 1, I need `number_1` in `number_index`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. Since you have to do for every row, you can use `lambda` function to get this done.

`table['number_index'] = table.apply(lambda x: x["number_" + str(x['index'])], axis = 1)`

Answer (score 1):

Using `lookup` after `str` `split` of the `columns` name

```
df1=df.copy()
df1.columns=df1.columns.str.split('_').str[-1]
df['Newval']=df1.lookup(df.index,df['index'].astype(str))
df
Out[34]: 
   number_1  number_2  number_3  number_100  index  Newval
0         1         2      2000           8      3    2000
1       201        10        21           2      1     201
```

Answer (score 0):

I don´t really understand your question. If you are looking to put a variable in a name I would suggest the `exec` command.

```
exec("table['number_index'] = " + f'''table['number_' + {str(table['index'])}]'''
```

Thus you can execute a string command. With `f'''{var_name}'''` you can combine strings and variables.